# MySQL:Error while inserting new data with Auto-Increment Id

Tags: mysql, jsp, mysql-workbench

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my error or coding? I have followed the tutorials on Internet but there is still some error with MySQL process.

**JSP code for inserting the data:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
import = "fyp1.controller2.Facade, fyp1.app.Local"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
    String loc = request.getParameter("location");
    Facade facade = new Facade();
    Local lcal = new Local(loc);

    int saje = facade.gettest(lcal);

    if(saje != 1){

%>
<jsp:forward page="test1.jsp" />
<%}
    else{
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="eror.jsp" />
     <%} %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Code for insert the data:**

```
    int gettest(Local local) throws SQLException
{   
    PreparedStatement ps = facade.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into local(local_id,local_name) values(SEQ.nextval,?)");
    ps.setString(1, local.getLocalName());

    int status = ps.executeUpdate();

    if(status == 1)
        facade.getConnection().commit();
    else
        facade.getConnection().rollback();

    return status;
}
```

**Error getting:**

[image: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: some line numbers to go with your stacktrace would be useful! What does `facade.getConnection()` do?

Comment: Probably not related to your error, but with MySQL, don't specify a value for the auto-incrememnt field.  `insert into local (local_name) values(?)`

Comment: @TomMac the facade.getCOnnection() will connect with the SQL Server. and for the case above, if the query execution is success, it will commit the operation. Else, it will rollback the operation.

Comment: @Tap I have also tried that. The result is error too. Then I try to search for other alternatives and found the query like this, but it is still the same.

Comment: According to the stack trace, a method is being called on a null object at line 59 of the `Facade` class, which is in the `gettest()` method.  Can you post that code?

Comment: dont need to show primary key field in insert query.if it auto increment it takes values automatically. nextval mostly used with oracle,not necessary in mysql

Comment: @TapcThe I have posted the code with the question at the above..

Comment: which line is line 59 of the `Facade` class?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing line numbers, but are you sure that localName has a value?  Is it coming from request parameter "location"?  What input are you getting for that request parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a MySQL database, but your SQL statement is using sequences, which are not supported - at least that way - by the MySQL (you need to declare tables with auto_increment option). So the call for preparing the statement will throw a SQLException and the null pointer exception could originate here.

You can check the correctness of your SQL statement just typing it inside the MySQL workbench or whatever program you use, replacing the '?' with an actual value, for example this way:

```
insert into local (local_id,local_name) 
values (SEQ.nextval,'ES');
```

As It is **not** going to work (MySQL you dont'have the possibility to define sequences), you'll discover the problem is at the SQL code side, and not with the Java/Jsp code side.

As a solution, you have to declare the *local_id* column as *auto_increment* column while creating your *local* table. 
Then  when you insert a new value for *local_name* inside the table:

```
insert into local(local_name) values (?)
```

an autogenerated value for the *local_id* will also transparently added.

Answer (score 0):

the error shows a null pointer.

at this line:

```
ps.setString(1, local.getLocalName());
```

you are setting the first parameter which is local_id 
with local.getLocalName().
how about the 2nd parameter local_name?
did you set any value for this?

```
PreparedStatement.setString(index x,String s)
```

the index x starts from 1.